# return to previous page with form complet

Tags: php, forms

Basically I have a registration form and when I click the submit button check if the email is valid.

However if there is a record of an error I do "header (" location: ". $ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']);" to go to previous page.
When this happens you need to write it all again in the form, how can I make the data to be filled?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to temporarily store the previously entered values in the session:

```
$_SESSION['prevPost'] = $_POST;
```

Then you can use them to re-populate the form when the original page is loaded:

```
<?php
    $prevPost = $_SESSION['prevPost'];
?>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $prevPost['email']; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a redirect if you are submitting to the same page that shows the form. Then you set the `value` of the form elements with the data passed in from the post and reshow the form. Your data will need to be escaped properly to prevent cross-site scripting attacks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

when you draw your form, you just need to check if the values are present.

```
$name = '';
if(!empty($_POST['name']){
    $name =  $_POST['name'];
}

<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>" />
```

Note: you should urlencode these values when applicable to curb xss attacks.